# Prove that the conective $\beta(a,b,c,d)=(a\implies b) \implies (c\implies d)$ is not adequate.

Tags: logic

A set C of conectives is called adequate if you every formula written with the conectives $\{\text{implies, and, not, or}\}$ has an equivalent formula written only with conectives from $C$.

Prove that the conective $\beta(a,b,c,d)=(a\implies b) \implies (c\implies d)$ is / is not not adequate.

I believe this conective is not adequate: I've come to think you can't form contradictions using it alone. Also, I could form the $\implies$ conective using $\beta$, thus $\{\beta, \implies\} \equiv\{\beta\}$ in terms of "formula making power".

E: I should add I haven't yet studied boolean algebras, so I really don't understand many terms.

Is it possible to make a (perhaps sillier) argument by contradiction, assuming there exists a contradiction expressible only with $\beta$ and reaching and absurdity?

Comment: Moreover, as $\beta$ is composed only of implication, with your notation, we also have $\{\Rightarrow\}\equiv\{\beta\}$, and the constant $\bot$ is indeed not deducable from it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with that symbol, what does it mean?

Comment: Ah, sorry, $\bot=$falsum. Neither negation can't be expressed by only $\Rightarrow$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, implication can be expressed by $\beta$, as $\ a\Rightarrow a\,=\,\top$ (true) always, and thus
$$a\Rightarrow b\ =\ \beta(a,a,a,b)$$
Also, as $\beta$ is composed only of implications, we have that the expressive power of $\beta$ is just *the same* as that of $\Rightarrow$.

Now, to see that the constant falsum $\bot$ can't be expressed, we can consider a map $f$ between Boolean algebras $\{\bot,\top\}\to\{\bot,\,x,\,\lnot x,\,\top\}$ sending $\bot\mapsto x$ and $\top\mapsto\top$. 
This map preserves $\Rightarrow$, thus also $\beta$, but doesn't preserve the zero element $\bot$.

Answer (score 2):

**Berci**’s proof is elegant; here’s a less elegant but perhaps slightly more elementary one. Start with the same observation, that the expressive power of $\beta$ is the same as that of $\Rightarrow$. Now suppose that we can express $\bot$ using only $\Rightarrow$; then among all expressions that do this, there must be one of shortest possible length. Since $\Rightarrow$ is the only available connective, this shortest formula must have the form $\varphi\Rightarrow\psi$ for some shorter formulas $\varphi$ and $\psi$. This formula $\varphi\Rightarrow\psi$ is false for all truth assignments to the proposition letters appearing in it, which means that $\varphi$ is always true, and $psi$ is always false. But that means that $\psi=\bot$, where $\psi$ is shorter than $\varphi\Rightarrow\psi$, contradicting the minimality of $\varphi\Rightarrow\psi$. Thus, there is no formula using only $\Rightarrow$ that expresses $\bot$, and $\{\Rightarrow\}$ (and hence $\{\beta\}$) is not complete.

Comment: Hmm I don't understand how to prove that the expressive power $\beta$ is equal to the one of $\rightarrow$, as I only proved that $Pow(\{\beta\})=Pow(\{\beta, \rightarrow \}$, could you explain a bit on that?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: It's in Berci's answer: $\beta$ can be expressed in terms of $\to$, so $Pow(\{\beta\})\subseteq Pow(\{\to\})$, and $\to$ can be expressed in terms of $\beta$, so you also have the opposite inclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Post's characterisation of [functional completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness) gives necessary and sufficient conditions for the adequacy of a set of propositional connectives. $\{\beta\}$ fails Post's test because $\beta(\top, \top, \top, \top) = \top$.

Comment: Woah, so if I have any $n$-ary conective $Q$ and I plug $(1,1,...,1)$ into it and it returns $1$, then $Q$ is not adequate? That's really cool!

Comment: That's exactly right. Testing whether a set of connectives is adequate is very straightforward using Post's characterisation.

Comment: Could you explain why that particular test works? I read the page on wikipedia, but to be honest it was too hard to understand for me, I don't really know much about this subject. Most I've seen are valuations, not boolean algebras, for example.

Comment: Negation converts $\top$ to $\bot$. How could you represent it using connectives that only map $(\top, \ldots, \top)$ to $\top$?

Comment: I don't understand why that is not possible, I'm sorry...

Comment: If you apply your connectives to arguments that are all $\top$ you will get $\top$. (It's like building formulas in arithmetic using only positive numbers, addition and multiplication: all your formulas will have positive values.)

Comment: Oh I see! As $(T,..,T)$ will always give $T$ it means that there are no contradictions ($\bot$, right?) I think I've got it!